# Which sounds better: the Google headquarters or Google's headquarters?

Tags: grammar

Which sounds better: **the Google headquarters** or **Google's headquarters**?

Comment: I don't think there's enough context here to say one way or the other – it would depend on what I was trying to say. I could imagine using either one, depending on the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you comparing '**the** Google headquarters' to **'Google's headquarters'** or you are concerned with **Google** or **Google's**. While I hope the use of *definite* article is clear, I think the question is about 'Google' or 'Google's' i.e. whether or not to use an apostrophe there.

You can drop an apostrophe 's' as 'Google' is serving there as an attributive noun. An attributive noun is a noun that modifies another noun serving as an adjective.

As a side note, maybe useful, you can also drop the apostrophe if the noun itself is ending with 's'. For instance, United States government.